# A measure of disconnectedness for points in the plane

Tags: graphs-and-networks, code-request, distance

I am inexperienced with *Mathematica*, so I apologize if I advertise my ignorance.

I am trying to write a code that will assign a measure of 'disconnectedness' to a finite set $S$ of points in the plane. In other words, I would like to define a function $\kappa$ that maps finite subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ to nonnegative real numbers. So if the points in $S$ all appear in one big clump, then $\kappa(S)$ should be small. One the other hand, if the points in $S$ appear in two or more clumps, then $\kappa(S)$ should be large.

One such measure might be obtained as follows. For each $\varepsilon>0$, define a graph $G_\varepsilon(S)$ with vertex set $S$ in which two points in $S$ are adjacent in the graph $G_\varepsilon(S)$ if and only if the (Euclidean) distance between them is less than $\varepsilon$. We would then let $$\kappa(S)=\inf\{\varepsilon:G_\varepsilon(S)\text{ is a connected graph}\}.$$
This works theoretically, but it seems as though it would be very computationally difficult to evaluate $\kappa(S)$ for, say, $1000$ different sets $S$, each having $1000$ elements. Even if the computing time were not an issue, I still would not know how to tell Mathematica to form the graphs $G_\varepsilon(S)$. I also would not know how to get Mathematica to determine whether or not $G_\varepsilon(S)$ is a connected graph.

Is there a nice way of coding some sort of 'disconnectedness measure', even if it is not the one I have described here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brute-force way to implement the one you described:

These are the points:

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {1000, 3}];
```

These are their pairwise distances:

```
dm = DistanceMatrix[pts];
```

Test connectedness for a given `epsilon`:

```
epsilon = 0.15;
ConnectedGraphQ@AdjacencyGraph@UnitStep[epsilon - dm]
(* True *)
```

Find a good approximation to the threshold `epsilon` using binary search:

```
Clear[binarySearch];
binarySearch[f_, n_, min_, max_] :=     
 Module[{left = min, right = max, mid},
  If[f[min] && Not@f[max], Return[$Failed]];
  Do[
   mid = (left + right)/2;
   If[f[mid],
    right = mid,
    left = mid
    ],
   {n}
   ];
  mid
  ]

binarySearch[
 ConnectedGraphQ@AdjacencyGraph@UnitStep[# - dm] &,
 50,
 0., 0.25
]

(* 0.123056 *)
```

Comment: This could be made faster by starting with a Delaunay triangulation instead of a complete distance matrix.  Cannot update the answer now, sorry.